# drupal 8.5 no toolbars active

Tags: installation, toolbar

I am new to drupal. I installed 8.5. via web-download, transferred it via ftp and extracted the tar-file via ssh. 
I managed to setup a mysql database and install it with drupal. Wonderful. I can add users and remove them, have administrative privileges.

There is a header with Toolbar items, but then only a link list is shown - tested with firefox and chromium. I have access to themes, can even install new ones. I tried to install Admin toolbar - no change.

I installed a mysql-percona-server Server version: 5.7.20-19-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release '19', Revision '3c5d3e5d53c'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure your `files` folder (by default at `sites/default/files`) is writable for the user your webserver is running with and also set a proper temporary files folder that is writable as well.

Comment: This ist not the issue, I think; the sites/default/files folder has the following permissions(): drwxrwx--- 7 -username- www-data  4096 Mar 12 23:30 files. username has admin role in drupal.

Comment: Then you will need to provide more details in your above description. It's hard to imagine the issue by reading the current question.

Comment: Would be interesting to know, what kind of additional details would help to clarify the issue. Nonetheless, "Solution" below.

Answer (score 0):

After extensive search (logfiles) and meddling about with access rights, 
modifying the file .htaccess did the trick.

https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/post-installation/2015-11-22/drupal8-after-installation-no-theme-applied

I commented the option line (first line) and set the file to read only.